# Cannot get the right data from an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

Here's my code:

```
XmlNodeList otherImageId =
    document.DocumentElement
            .SelectNodes("/OHManager/config/customimage/image/@id");

XmlNodeList otherImage =
    document.DocumentElement
            .SelectNodes("/OHManager/config/customimage/image");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Image Id" + otherImageId[i].InnerText.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("File name" + otherImage[i].InnerText.ToString());
}
```

The XML:

```
<OHManager>
  <config type="image">
    <customimage no="5">
      <image id="1">Sea Wallpaper.jpg</image>
      <image id="2">Sea Wallpaper.jpg</image>
      <image id="3">Sea Wallpaper.jpg</image>
      <image id="4">Sea Wallpaper.jpg</image>
      <image id="5">Sea Wallpaper.jpg</image>
    </customimage>
  </config>
</OHManager>
```

The output:

```
Image Id1
File name10101010
Image Id2
File name10101010
Image Id3
File name10101010
Image Id4
File name10101010
Image Id5
```

Notice how there are lines `File name10101010`.  I cannot figure out how to get the correct file name: `Sea Wallpaper.jpg`.  It's giving me the image id but not the file name.

Comment: My Xml:

<OHManager>
  <config type="image">     
  <customimage no="5">
  <image id="1">Sea Wallpaper.jpg</image>
  <image id="2">Sea Wallpaper.jpg</image>
  <image id="3">Sea Wallpaper.jpg</image>
  <image id="4">Sea Wallpaper.jpg</image>
  <image id="5">Sea Wallpaper.jpg</image>
 </customimage>
  </OHManager>                THIS WAS THE XML STRUCTURE.
  </config>

Comment: Your queries look fine.  Can you run it again to see if that is the actual output?

Comment: hi jeff thnx 4 rply.yep this is the output,I am still getting it.

Comment: thnx jeff 4 editing my code..It's kinda mess before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to perform 2 XPath queries against your xml document, one will suffice. This code should demonstrate how to get bothe the `id` attribute and the inner text of the node:

```
XmlNodeList list = document.DocumentElement
                        .SelectNodes("/OHManager/config/customimage/image");

foreach(XmlElement node in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Image Id: {0}, FileName: {1}",
               node.Attributes["id"].Value,
               node.Value);
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=THABU16531

Comment: hey yo ,every one who helped me,thnx for ur help,the problem was in my xml I use the same structure before.so it gives me wrong output. still thnx for u guys.